# requests to issue auth token from Microsoft Cognitive API return 500 with stack trace

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am posting this as instructed by [@AzureSupport on Twitter](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/826127561927204864).

All calls to [the Cognitive auth API](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken) are returning 500 with a stack trace and this happens for all my subscription keys. This was working correctly and suddenly stopped.

This happens from my application, from curl, and even from the Microsoft test form [here](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html).

curl:

```
curl --header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <my-key>' --data "" 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken'
```

The pertinent error in the stack trace appears to be:

```
[AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key used is expired., ... redacted ...]
```

This happens with keys that have been operating correctly for months. It also happens with newly generated keys for testing.

Comment: We're investigating this now.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well, problems started 5-6 hours ago. Just want to let you now your not the only one.

Comment: We have identified the cause and are working on correcting it now.

Comment: It is working again