# Authentication suddenly stopped working?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using the authentication API as directed here: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html

Everything was working fine for about a week and suddenly today at around 11:55pm eastern time, all calls to get a new token give 500 errors with the following stack:

http://pastebin.com/uQ3VL6Am

We simply make a POST request to https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken
with header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' set to our key

I tried using our second API key, and it still does not work.  I tried regenerating another key, and it still does not work.  Our account manager says that the account should be in good standing.

Thank you

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. This is a problem on their side even though the current status suggest everything works fine: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status. Here is a tweet stating they are investigating the issue: https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/826147294714097664

Comment: Related SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942838/requests-to-issue-auth-token-from-microsoft-cognitive-api-return-500-with-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by Microsoft as of 6pm PST 1/30/17.